# I saw a strange cluster of stars, help!

Tags: star, star-systems

On January 1, 2024 in the sky above Almaty region, at about 19:05-19:10, I saw a line of stars that flew in one even line that disappeared in the distance, the stars were not very bright, but they were seen very clearly, what is it called and what is it?

Comment: If you need to send a picture, I'm willing to email it to you

Comment: Hello, this was a starlink train,  a group of satellites launched by SpaceX.  After launch they are close together, but they gradually drift apart.  See the linked Q and A